# Eureka client not registering to server in docker spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, docker, spring-mvc, docker-compose, netflix-eureka

The eureka server and client is working if i run locally but with docker compose i am getting error Connection Refused. Below are the configuration which i am using.

Eureka server property file (Discovery Service):

```
spring.application.name=eureka-server
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

Eureka client property file (Gateway service)

```
server.port=8762
spring.application.name=gateway-service
#tried eureka.client.service-url.default-zone with localhost and hostip as well (Not working)
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://sm-discovery:8761/eureka
```

Docker file of Eureka Server (Discovery Service)

```
From tomcat:9.0.48-jdk11-openjdk-slim
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/*
COPY ./target/discovery-service.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

Docker file of Eureka Client (Gateway Service)

```
From tomcat:9.0.48-jdk11-openjdk-slim
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/*
COPY ./target/discovery-service.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3"
services:
  sm-discovery:
    image: sm-discovery
    container_name: sm-discovery
    build: ./discovery-service
    ports:
      - "8761:8080"
    restart: always
  sm-gateway:
    image: sm-gateway
    container_name: sm-gateway
    build: ./gateway-service
    ports:
      - "8762:8080"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - sm-discovery
```

When i build and run docker compose, i am getting following error in eureka client:

```
Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://sm-discovery:8761/eureka/}, exception=I/O error on POST request for "http://sm-discovery:8761/eureka/apps/GATEWAY-SERVICE": Connect to sm-discovery:8761 [sm-discovery/172.29.0.2] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to sm-discovery:8761 [sm-discovery/172.29.0.2] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused) stacktrace=org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://sm-discovery:8761/eureka/apps/GATEWAY-SERVICE": Connect to sm-discovery:8761 [sm-discovery/172.29.0.2] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to sm-discovery:8761 [sm-discovery/172.29.0.2] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711)
```

Docker network inspect:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "social-media_default",
        "Id": "0513ee1d4b80f21723e772f7eb3a100d9d78f3cb2a7a10a0f78bf5eb57ec4c6a",
        "Created": "2022-12-27T10:32:37.9902248Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.29.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.29.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "43f35536a4cb8470b8a3278de9a62bc26284be9955409b83fba6c2d210995d42": {
                "Name": "sm-discovery",
                "EndpointID": "4babebdfadcf8a233e21ae87eea6d38ac22b0a75231505846eac97331127e24c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1d:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.29.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "634c47e82d3c9d2dd85c9e23830a3bc579a874171dcb021a44d78041adb17fab": {
                "Name": "sm-gateway",
                "EndpointID": "3b2b128b8cd11b713cc0d19d5187bdf0d7503eeff03389449a3094ff221f1366",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1d:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.29.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "social-media",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.12.1"
        }
    }
]
```

I have checked many solutions in stackoverflow but none worked. Can someone please let me know what is the error here ?